# When remote downloading a file, what is the earliest point at which I can verify whether it's malicious or not?

Tags: php, security, download, file-transfer

When downloading a file remotely, is it safe to download the file, and *then* check whether it's a valid file, or is it too late once it's on the webserver?

I'm creating a script to download images remotely, so right now I perform the following steps

- Verify a valid URL was submitted
- Check if the last 3 characters of the URL are an allowed extension
- Get the headers of the file, and check if the *content-length* is within the size limits
- Downloading the file to a string using `file_get_contents()` (with the *content-length* value specified as the *length* parameter (which should stop people submitting huge files with an incorrect *content-length*)
- Inputting the string into `createimagefromstring()` and making sure it returns true
- Writing the file

Is there anything wrong with doing this? Do I need to check anything else before I downloading the file to a string?

Comment: it's php. you can't do ANYTHING until the upload completes. your code literally will not be run until after the last byte of data shows up at the server. if you want to validate during the upload, you can't use php.

Comment: @MarcB but is there anything I can check remotely before I use `file_get_contents()`? I could then exit the script if there's a problem before I download the content. As for the local uploading (by browser) I already have that taken care of

Comment: you could always do curl and request byte ranges. e.g. download 1k, which would let you check things like magic numbers and see if it even LOOKS like it should be what it claims to be.